# Local installation of eZ Platform can't connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, doctrine, composer-php, ezplatform

I'm trying (in vain) to run eZ Platform locally (macOS v10.14.6) following the guide @ https://doc.ezplatform.com/en/latest/community_resources/installing-on-mac-os-and-windows/.

I used Homebrew to install MySQL + PHP 7.3.

All goes well until I run **composer ezplatform-install**. The installer never prompts me for any parameters as stated in the docs. Moreover this happens:

```
> @php bin/console ezplatform:install clean
Creating the database ezp if it does not exist, executing command doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
The configured database 'ezp' does not exist or cannot be created (An error occurred when executing the "'doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists'" command.).
Please check the database configuration in 'app/config/parameters.yml'
Script @php bin/console ezplatform:install clean handling the ezplatform-install event returned with error code 4
```

I have couple of issues with this cruel shell feedback:

- There's no **app/config/parameters.yml** whatsoever, configuration lives in a **.env** file
- I have MySQL up and running and an 'ezp' database does exist.

Configuration-wise here are my **.env** settings

```
# Doctrine DBAL
DATABASE_USER=user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_NAME=ezp
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_PLATFORM=mysql
DATABASE_DRIVER=pdo_mysql
```

I also added the server_version to **doctrine.yaml** as recommended on a few threads I found on this topic. My problem persisted...

```
# configure these for your database server
driver: pdo_mysql
server_version: 8.0.18
charset: '%database_charset%'
default_table_options:
  charset: '%database_charset%'
  collate: '%database_collation%'
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the database and let eZ Platforme create it.

Regards.